How to make a normal UV without seams?
For a long time I tried to figure out this topic myself, but I still did not understand how to make a UV scan on an object like this (mine). Nasty seams always appear, or the texture is stretched too much. Please help me, I will be very grateful. (translated with the help of a translator)



I'm afraid the topology is not good, maybe redo a clean object from scratch?

This is not the first time I've made an object of this shape, but this time I decided to use the built-in remesher, could it really mess up the topology?

maybe tell a bit more about your whole project?

I'm creating a game where the action takes place in a mine. I have already modeled most of the entire map and there are such seams everywhere, I thought to leave these seams as they are, but still it greatly spoils the impression

changed the post, added a screenshot of how it looks in the texture engine

If you don't want seams, you could unwrap for example with the Smart UV Project option, give your object a black Image Texture, and paint a texture on it with the Stencil option of the Draw brush, where does your rock texture come from?

if I can't find any more options, I will do so, thank you

I am applying material to an object in the engine, would it be more correct to draw the entire texture on this object myself?

You should try what I suggest, have you?

Okay, I'll try it.
